# How to test onChange in React?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a `<Input />` component and I need test onChange handler method, but the simulate method not works and when I test the change property it's the state that doesn't change.

Below it's how I use the `<Input />` component:

```
...
let formFields = formElementsArray.map(formElement => (
        <Input
            key={formElement.id}
            elementType={formElement.config.elementType}
            elementConfig={formElement.config.elementConfig}
            value={formElement.config.value}
            invalid={!formElement.config.valid}
            shouldValidate={formElement.config.validation}
            touched={formElement.config.touched}
            changed={(event) => inputChangeHandler(event, formElement.id)} />
    ))
...
```

Below it is my `<Input />` component:

```
import React from 'react';

import styles from './Input.module.css';

const input = (props) => {
    let inputElement = null;
    const inputClasses = [styles.InputElement];

    if (props.invalid && props.shouldValidate && props.touched) {
        inputClasses.push(styles.Invalid);
    }

    switch (props.elementType) {
        case ('input'):
            inputElement = <input
                className={inputClasses.join(' ')}
                {...props.elementConfig}
                value={props.value}
                onChange={props.changed} />;
            break;
        case ('textarea'):
            inputElement = <textarea
                className={inputClasses.join(' ')}
                {...props.elementConfig}
                value={props.value}
                onChange={props.changed} />;
            break;
        case ('select'):
            inputElement = <select
                className={inputClasses.join(' ')}
                {...props.elementConfig}
                value={props.value}
                onChange={props.changed}>
                {props.elementConfig.options.map(option => (
                    <option
                        key={option.value}
                        value={option.value}>{option.displayValue}</option>
                ))}
            </select>;
            break;
        default:
            inputElement = <input
                className={inputClasses.join(' ')}
                {...props.elementConfig}
                value={props.value}
                onChange={props.changed} />;
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.Input}>
            {props.label && <label className={styles.Label}>{props.label}</label>}
            {inputElement}
        </div>
    )
};

export default input;
```

Below it is how I test the onChange:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import { configure, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';

import { Auth } from './Auth';
import Spinner from '../../components/UI/Spinner/Spinner';
import Button from '../../components/UI/Button/Button';
import Input from '../../components/UI/Input/Input';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

const setup = () => {
    const props = {
        onAuth: jest.fn()
    }

    const enzymeWrapper = shallow(<Auth {...props} />);

    return {
        enzymeWrapper,
        props
    }
}

describe('<Auth />', () => {

    it('should create user when form is submitted', () => {
        const { enzymeWrapper: wrapper, props: reduxProps } = setup();
        const form = wrapper.find('form');
        const inputs = form.find(Input);
        const emailInput = inputs.at(0);
        const passwordInput = inputs.at(1);
        const email = "email@servidor.com";
        const password = "senha";

        // below the onChange doesn't works
        emailInput.simulate('change', {
            target: {
                value: email
            }
        });
        passwordInput.simulate('change', {
            target: {
                value: password
            }
        });
        // below the onChange doesn't works
        emailInput.find('input').simulate('change', {
            target: {
                value: email
            }
        });
        passwordInput.find('input').simulate('change', {
            target: {
                value: password
            }
        });
        // below the onChange works, but state doesn't change
        emailInput.props().changed({
            target: {
                value: email
            }
        }, 0);
        passwordInput.props().changed({
            target: {
                value: password
            }
        }, 1);

        expect(emailInput.props().value).toEqual(email);
        expect(passwordInput.props().value).toEqual(password);
    });
});
```

My reasoning is right? How I test the onChange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the right direction, just missing a couple of things.

First, React Hooks may be tricky to test, but you are actually not using hooks (at least not in the code you posted), so don't worry about it :)

Second, your test is missing the `expect` statement. When you are testing, you want to check if something worked, and you use `expect` for that.

So, after this piece of code:

```
emailInput.simulate('change', {
    target: {
        value: email
    }
});
```

You could have something like:

```
expect(emailInput.value).toEqual(email);
```

You can follow the example from Enzyme documentation [here](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/simulate.html).

Also, you can check the documentation of `expect` [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect.html).

Comment: This doesn't work. Please read with more attention for my tests code I had mentioned that this piece of code doesn't simulate the onChange. I don't know if it's why my component hasn't the onChange but it's the input children because if I replace the `changed={}` property to onChange in `<Input />` it works but it's not correct. I have knowledge about the documentation, thanks for the suggestion. The lack of expect is intentional my goal it simulates change.

Comment: I think I am a little bit confused. First, how do you check that the `onChange` did not work without an expect? Second, why do you have a unit test without an `expect`? Sorry, just trying to understand your situation...

Comment: Yeah, I agree this is confused I ended up to add a expect at the issue. But doesn't work with your suggestion yet.

Comment: If you try `expect(emailInput.value).toEqual(email);` instead of `expect(emailInput.props().value).toEqual(email);` (removind the `props()`), does it work? What does the error say? It should have something like "Expected ... Received ..." when you run Jest

Comment: I already test with the code suggested but doesn't work. First, the simulate doesn't run the `onChange` method I know this because I put a `console.log` in the method and the state doesn't change. I ever do other similar tests with this and works but not in this situation when the component doesn't have the `onChange` but is a property and the `onChange` are in element input HTML inside the component.

Comment: This is getting long for a SO discussion. I will DM you on Twitter so we can talk and we can come back here when we have a better answer.